# C++: is instance descendant of class

Tags: c++

Assume we have three classes A, B and C. B is derived from A and C is derived from B.
Now we have a pointer that points to an object of class A. Due to Polymorphism it can actually point to instances of all three classes.

With typeid() i can check what type the pointer actually refers to. But I'm trying to determine if it points to any descendant of class B. That is to say I'm looking for some kind of IsDescendantOf(unkownclass, baseclass) function. Is there a why to do so in C++?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this exact scenario has been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760365/possible-to-use-typeid-to-determine-parent-child-relationship

Comment: If you're using polymorphism correctly, you'll very rarely need `dynamic_cast<T>()`. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Use `dynamic_cast`.  It returns NULL on failure:

```
B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
```

You may find this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can also test this using template meta programming, at compile time. It even works if the classes in question do not have any virtual functions, which `dynamic_cast` won't.

```
template <typename D, typename B>
class is_derived_from {
   class No { };
   class Yes { No no[2]; };

   static Yes Test(B*);
   static No  Test(...);
public:
   enum { inherits = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };
   static bool is_derived() { return inherits; }
};
```

I think this is derived from one of the excellent [GoTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/) series.

Comment: That only works if the type of what the pointer contains is known at compile time. And if it was known there, one should probably use something like [`boost::type_traits::is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) instead.

Comment: It wasn't quite clear from the question if this was actually known at compile time or if it had to be run time. Using boost instead of the DIY solution is a good point though.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast an object via `dynamic_cast<TargetType*>(ptr)` and then check if the result is null (cannot cast - not a descendant) or not.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::is_base_of` from `<type_traits>` and `static_assert` to check at compile time